# Datatype conversion error in Hive CASE statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a HiveQL query that looks something like:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        CASE WHEN col_a = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (col_b / col_a) END AS math_is_fun
FROM    (/* derived query*/) AS x ;
```

When I execute this in Hive, I recently started getting the error `FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line X:Y ArgumentTypeMismatch 'col_a': The expression after ELSE should have the same type as those after THEN: "int" is expected but "double" is found.`

While I understand that there's a data type mismatch between the literal `0` and the result of `(col_a / col_b)`, I'm not clear why Hive is choking on this and, more importantly, what the best course of action is to resolve this error. Should I cast the literal `0` as a `double` or is there a better approach?

This is Hive 0.8.1 running in Amazon EMR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is some odd behavior assuming col_a and col_b are both `ints`. The literal `0` is of course an `int`, and according the [wiki tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/tutorial.html) division "Gives the result of dividing B from A. The type of the result is the same as the common parent(in the type hierarchy) of the types of the operands. If the operands are integer types, then the result is the quotient of the division" so it should be an `int` as well.

I'm running Hive 0.10.0 and getting the same error as you, `(col_b / col_a)` looks like a `double` but should be an `int`. This looks like a bug to me, but maybe there is something subtle in the spec about it I haven't found.

There are a couple of solutions.

```
SELECT  ID, 
    CASE WHEN col_a = 0 THEN CAST(0 AS DOUBLE)
    ELSE (col_b / col_a) END AS math_is_fun
FROM    (/* derived query*/) AS x ;
```

and

```
SELECT  ID, 
    CASE WHEN col_a = 0 THEN 0.0
    ELSE (col_b / col_a) END AS math_is_fun
FROM    (/* derived query*/) AS x ;
```

are equivalent, but I think you probably want

```
SELECT  ID, 
    CASE WHEN col_a = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE CAST((col_b / col_a) AS INT) END AS math_is_fun
FROM    (/* derived query*/) AS x ;
```

assuming `col_a` and `col_b` are both `ints` and you want the result to be integer division, as specified in the wiki. Hopefully someone else will come along and suggest your hypothetical "better approach".

If either `col_a` or `col_b` are double, or you want the result to be floating point division, ignore everything else I said and just change`0` to `0.0` so it no longer looks like an `int` to Hive.

Comment: Using 0.0 fixed it. I don't understand why this happened, but that fixed it.